# Why is my nexus port different?

Tags: maven, nexus

I've installed Nexus on my computer under CentOS 7.2 and configured the port to be 8281.

[image: Different port]
[image: Config]

Why is the the repositories's port of access address 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got "force base URL" set under "administration/server" in the UI?  If so, uncheck that.

Comment: Thank for your help. I still can't find the mistake.I changed port to 80,it works.